# TCP Timeouts in Nginx

Tags: nginx, timeout

I am running about sixty webservers on a Proxmox Cluster (uses KVM). The VMs are running the most recent version of Debian 11. They use nginx, different versions of PHP-FPM and MariaDB. I follow a infrastructure-as-code-approch, all the servers with some exceptions in our infrastrucure like jitsi are provisioned by ansible and therefore nearly identical. I host standard Typo3-Installations as well as more complex applications usually developed in Laravel. Some time ago I started configuring active checks in CheckMK (the checks use a plugin from Nagios called check_http) for our infrastructure and projects of our customers which had gone live, meaning accessible from the outside.

After this I started getting timeout errors at the frequency of about one or two a day spread seemingly at random accross the twenty servers which I monitor with active checks. At first I considered this to be simply false positives, but last Friday it happened during a Jitsi Conference and was reported to me by a colleague. I checked the logs of nginx and found the following entries for the exact time period in which Checkmk couldn't reach the server, which is less than one minute (time between checks, the next check is always negative, meaning no errors) and probably only a few seconds. What is the cause of this problem and how can I fix it? Do you have a suggestion how I could reproduce and then further analyze the problem?

Checkmk-Error-Message:

Summary connect to address 195.34.XXX.XXX and port 443: Connection refused
Details HTTP CRITICAL - Unable to open TCP socket

Checkmk-Recovery-Message:

Summary HTTP OK: HTTP/1.1 200 OK - 59404 bytes in 0.008 second response time

Nginx error log:

2022/09/16 11:18:42 [alert] 3212994#3212994: *2590 open socket #18 left in connection 5

2022/09/16 11:18:42 [alert] 3212994#3212994: *2494 open socket #15 left in connection 8

2022/09/16 11:18:42 [alert] 3212994#3212994: *2533 open socket #16 left in connection 9

2022/09/16 11:18:42 [alert] 3212994#3212994: *2534 open socket #17 left in connection 10

2022/09/16 11:18:42 [alert] 3212994#3212994: *2591 open socket #20 left in connection 11

2022/09/16 11:18:42 [alert] 3212994#3212994: *2573 open socket #24 left in connection 12

2022/09/16 11:18:42 [alert] 3212994#3212994: *2532 open socket #10 left in connection 13

2022/09/16 11:18:42 [alert] 3212994#3212994: *3230 open socket #28 left in connection 14

2022/09/16 11:18:42 [alert] 3212994#3212994: *2467 open socket #19 left in connection 15

2022/09/16 11:18:42 [alert] 3212994#3212994: *2535 open socket #21 left in connection 16

2022/09/16 11:18:42 [alert] 3212994#3212994: *3233 open socket #27 left in connection 17

2022/09/16 11:18:42 [alert] 3212994#3212994: *2771 open socket #30 left in connection 22

2022/09/16 11:18:42 [alert] 3212994#3212994: *2770 open socket #29 left in connection 23

2022/09/16 11:18:42 [alert] 3212994#3212994: *3234 open socket #22 left in connection 24

2022/09/16 11:18:42 [alert] 3212994#3212994: *3229 open socket #11 left in connection 26

2022/09/16 11:18:42 [alert] 3212994#3212994: *3231 open socket #32 left in connection 28

2022/09/16 11:18:42 [alert] 3212994#3212994: aborting

2022/09/16 11:20:19 [error] 3295994#3295994: *153 upstream timed out (110: Connection timed out) while reading response>

Yours sincerely

Stefan Malte Schumacher

Comment: IIRC, the alert `open socket ## left in connection #` happens when a socket is left open after a nginx process thread is shutdown.  There is a debugging note about this on the [nginx wiki](https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/tutorials/debugging/#socket-leaks).  This type of problem can exhaust your available TCP sockets, preventing new connections.  Make sure your processes running under nginx are closing their sockets properly, if you believe they are already supposed to be doing that then something is interrupting the proper closing of sockets.

Answer (score 3):

This could be caused by too little "max number of open file soft limit".
I saw that the default in Debian changed from 65536 to 1024.
This could be insufficient for nginix.
Verify this in consolle by typing:

```
ulimit -n
```

to be sure of the limit that nginx is using check the PID of an istance of it by typing:

```
 ps aux |grep nginx
```

you obtain some rows like:

```
www-data  148105  0.0  0.1  59100  5492 ?        S    Feb09   0:00 nginx: worker process
```

take the PID of one process (second column) and then:

```
cat /proc/[PID]/limits
     
cat /proc/148105/limits # in this example
```

Search for the row:

```
Max open files            8192                 8192                 files
```

if you get 1024 instead of 8192 add the following line at the beginning (main section) of  ngnix config file (nginx.conf):

```
worker_rlimit_nofile 8192;
```

You can obv. use bigger numbers.
Finally, restart the ngnix daemon and check new values with the above procedure.